# Couldn't make changes in users/session/new file in rails used with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I installed devise in my application and signup, signin and all the actions are working fine. 
I just replaced my heading from "Log in" to "sign in", it is not affected in the application. 
Please help me out.

This is the command i run after installing  devise

**$ rails generate devise User**

users/sessions/new:

### Sign in

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

routes.rb:

```
  devise_for :users
```

And i haven't created any controllers for devise.

Comment: override default views, check documentation of devise.

Answer (score 0):

In the file config/initializers/devise.rb, make

`# config.scoped_views = false` to

```
 config.scoped_views = true
```